# PeerJS text chat

Tags: javascript, websocket, peerjs

I am currently writing a web based chat client where two people connect to each other randomly and are thrown into the chat together with no prompting.

I am using the PeerJS library since I found it to be the most understandable one for me. I am at a blocking point though: I am not sure how to actually implement the text chat.

I have looked at their example on their site ([here](http://cdn.peerjs.com/demo/chat.html)) and I have modified the code slightly to work for me (mostly just how it looks and what some of the output is).

A problem I encountered is that their code requires two people to enter the other's id manually and the chat won't start without both people's verification (meaning, they both have to enter the id and press a "Connect" button).

Below is some code I have ran through my head to try to work out:

First I have to listen for the connection with PeerJS:

```
myPeer.on("connection", function() {...});
```

But at the same time, I want to listen for opening a connection on the same client, since I don't want to have to prompt the users for each other's ids:

```
myConn.on("open", function() {...})
```

But this is not possible (as far as I know) since I can't know what `myConn` will be until I open a connection with the `myPeer` listener above.

My problem is that I don't know how to do those simultaneously. If it helps at all, I am attempting to do video chat alongside this, which I have all figured out so if I could somehow piggyback off of that connection or whatever, that works too. I have total control over the project so I can pretty much do whatever I want (including switch libraries, if one is either easier to use or more developed).

Comment: did you find a way to share ids

Answer (score 2):

the `connection` event gives you a `DataConnection` instance.

Consider the following code on the receiving end:

```
var peer = new Peer('clientID');
peer.on('connection', function(con){
    con.on('data', function(data){
        console.log('Incoming data', data);
        con.send('REPLY');
    });
});
```

Now use this code on the sending end:

```
var peer = new Peer();
var con = peer.connect('clientID');
con.on('data', function(data){ ... });
con.send('HELLO WORLD');
```

Its important to wait for the connections to be open before sending messages. For the above you could use the `con.on('open', function(){ ... });`

`DataConnections` behave similar to TCP sockets. If you want two-way communication you can use 2 sockets from 2 peers. Since this question is a couple of months old I'm leaving the double socket solution for now. Let me know if you still need it.

Comment: Ivanhoe, what about if I want to send messages and files in the same chat. I was looking at https://github.com/peers/peerjs/blob/master/examples/chat.html but this implementation did not work to me. Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Sorry Moh, I moved to SimpleWebRTC and signalmaster a while ago. I would have multiple data connections, one for the files and one for the chat.

Comment: I finally have something working but I guess it is the wrong way because I am creating a new connection each time I want to send a text or a file. I tried to create only two connections as you suggested but could not make it. Could you please give some tips how solve it? This is my code https://github.com/simo163/webrtc/blob/apprtc/app/controllers/application.js

Comment: So peer.on("connection", f) is fired on every message? If so, why not save state like this: peer.on("connection", function(c){ if(chatConnected!==null) return; chatConnected = c; ...

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation, there is no way of connecting to a peer without knowing its ID
As they mentioned here https://peerjs.com/docs.html#start
When we want to connect to another peer, we'll need to know their peer id. You're in charge of communicating the peer IDs between users of your site.

I suggest you to use socket.io (or another instant data transfer means you prefer) for communicating these IDs

```js
var peer = new Peer();
peer.on('open', function(id) {
  console.log('My peer ID is: ' + id); //this will show you your ID
});

//then to connect to another peer
var conn = peer.connect('destination-peer-id'); //here you will use the destination peer that you have received using socket.io or another instant data transfer means you prefer
```